# NLog | logging to database is not working asp.net core Blazor Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm trying to add nlog to log to the file system (completed and working) and the database (not working).

I've tried everything with many posts and I can't seem to get the right configuration to work.

Here is my setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog-AspNetCore.txt">

    <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    <add assembly="NLog.Appsettings.Standard" />
    </extensions>

    <!-- the targets to write to -->
    <targets>
        <!-- File Target for all log messages with basic details -->
        <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-AspNetCore-all-${shortdate}.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id:whenEmpty=0}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

        <!-- File Target for own log messages with extra web details using some ASP.NET core renderers -->
        <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-AspNetCore-svc27-${shortdate}.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id:whenEmpty=0}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}|${callsite}" />

        <!--Console Target for hosting lifetime messages to improve Docker / Visual Studio startup detection -->
        <target xsi:type="Console" name="lifetimeConsole" layout="${MicrosoftConsoleLayout}" />

    <target xsi:type="Database"
         name="database"
         keepConnection="true"
         useTransactions="true"
         connectionString="${appsettings:name=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}"
         dbProvider="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient">

      <commandText>
        INSERT INTO dbo.NLogItems (Id, EventDateTime, EventLevel, UserName, MachineName, EventMessage, ErrorSource, ErrorClass, ErrorMethod, ErrorMessage, InnerErrorMessage)
        VALUES (NEWID(), @EventDateTime, @EventLevel, @UserName, @MachineName, @EventMessage, @ErrorSource, @ErrorClass, @ErrorMethod, @ErrorMessage, @InnerErrorMessage)
      </commandText>
      <parameter name="@EventDateTime" layout="${date:s}" />
      <parameter name="@EventLevel" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@UserName" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
      <parameter name="@MachineName" layout="${machinename}" />
      <parameter name="@EventMessage" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorSource" layout="${event-context:item=error-source}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorClass" layout="${event-context:item=error-class}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorMethod" layout="${event-context:item=error-method}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorMessage" layout="${event-context:item=error-message}" />
      <parameter name="@InnerErrorMessage" layout="${event-context:item=inner-error-message}" />
    </target>
    </targets>


    <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
    <rules>
        <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

        <!--Output hosting lifetime messages to console target for faster startup detection -->
        <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" minlevel="Info" writeTo="lifetimeConsole, ownFile-web" final="true" />

        <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs (BlackHole) -->
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
        <logger name="System.Net.Http.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />

        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

```
Drop table if exists [NLogItems]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NLogItems](
    [Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    [EventDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EventLevel] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [MachineName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [EventMessage] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ErrorSource] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ErrorClass] [nvarchar](512)  NULL,
    [ErrorMethod] [nvarchar](512)  NULL,
    [ErrorMessage] [nvarchar](max)  NULL,
    [InnerErrorMessage] [nvarchar](max)  NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NLogItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Here is a picture of my Nugets:

[image]

I've also looked in SQL Profiler and it seems like the `Insert` statement is not even coming across the wire.

Comment: Why `<parameter name="@EventDateTime" layout="${date:s}" />`? NLog 4.6+ support dbtypes so you can send it as a native datetime value instead of a string, i.e.: `<parameter name="@EventDateTime" layout="${date}" dbtype="DateTime" />` ref: [SQL Statement](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Database-target#sql-statement)

Comment: Also, `${event-context}` is deprecated, you should be using `${event-properties}` now. ref: [EventProperties Layout Renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer)

Comment: I want to log errors into the database, I was wondering how you built logging around blazor pages etc. Can you share some examples?

Answer (score 4):

NLog 5.0 introduces [several breaking changes](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html), and one is extracting the Database-Target into its own [NLog.Database](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Database) nuget-package. So you need to install this nuget-package to use database-target.

It is always a good idea to look at the [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) output to diagnose issues with NLog. It should say something like:

```
ArgumentException: Target type-alias is unknown: 'Database'. Extension NLog.Database not included?
```

Alternative one can enable `throwConfigExceptions="true"` and it will throw exceptions when detecting issues with NLog config:

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwConfigExceptions="true"
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: This was the fix! Thank you. I didn't know the logs were pushed there. I'll post my full example.

Answer (score 1):

Full working example after responses from Rolf Kristensen and
AlwaysLearning

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog-AspNetCore.txt">

    <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
        <add assembly="NLog.Appsettings.Standard" />
    </extensions>

    <!-- the targets to write to -->
    <targets>
        <!-- File Target for all log messages with basic details -->
        <target xsi:type="File" name="allfile" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-AspNetCore-all-${shortdate}.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id:whenEmpty=0}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

        <!-- File Target for own log messages with extra web details using some ASP.NET core renderers -->
        <target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="c:\temp\nlog-AspNetCore-svc27-${shortdate}.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id:whenEmpty=0}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}|${callsite}" />

        <!--Console Target for hosting lifetime messages to improve Docker / Visual Studio startup detection -->
        <target xsi:type="Console" name="lifetimeConsole" layout="${MicrosoftConsoleLayout}" />

    <target xsi:type="Database"
         name="dbPush"
         keepConnection="true"
         useTransactions="true"
          connectionString="${appsettings:name=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}"
            dbProivder="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient,Microsoft.Data.SqlClient">

      <commandText>
        INSERT INTO dbo.NLogItems ([Id]
        ,[EventDateTime]
        ,[EventLevel]
        ,[UserName]
        ,[MachineName]
        ,[EventMessage]
        ,[ErrorMessage]
        ,[ErrorType]
        ,[ErrorSource]
        ,[ErrorStackTrace]
        ,[InnerErrorMessage])
        VALUES (NEWID(), @EventDateTime, @EventLevel, @UserName, @MachineName, @EventMessage, 
               @ErrorMessage, @ErrorType, @ErrorSource, @ErrorStackTrace, @InnerErrorMessage)
      </commandText>

      <parameter name="@EventDateTime" layout="${date}" dbtype="DateTime" />
      <parameter name="@EventLevel" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@UserName" layout="${environment-user}" />
      <parameter name="@MachineName" layout="${machinename}" />
      <parameter name="@EventMessage" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorMessage" layout="${exception:format=message}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorType" layout="${exception:format=type}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorSource" layout="${exception:format=source}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorStackTrace" layout="${exception:format=stacktrace}" />
      <parameter name="@InnerErrorMessage" layout="${exception:format=type,message,method,source,stacktrace:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method,source,stacktrace}" />
    </target>
    </targets>


    <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
    <rules>
        <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allfile" />

        <!--Output hosting lifetime messages to console target for faster startup detection -->
        <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" minlevel="Info" writeTo="lifetimeConsole, ownFile-web" final="true" />

        <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs (BlackHole) -->
        <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
        <logger name="System.Net.Http.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />

        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownFile-web" />

    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="dbPush" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NLogItems](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [EventDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EventLevel] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [MachineName] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [EventMessage] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ErrorMessage] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ErrorType] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [ErrorSource] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ErrorStackTrace] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [InnerErrorMessage] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_NLogItems] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\;Database=Blazor_DEV;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "SessionTimeoutSettings": {
    "SessionTimeout": 15
  },
}
```

[image]

[image]